# Indentation and tabs in emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs

In our company, we have people who use Windows,OS-X and Ubuntu for writing code (mainly javascript) and I use mainly Emacs as my text editor.

However, I am quite new to Emacs, and I find the whole tab vs spaces customisation a bit confusing.

This is what the settings files for my friend's `Visual Studio Code` looks like

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
"editor.tabSize": 4,
"editor.insertSpaces": false,

"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
}
```

How do I replicate the same settings on Emacs?
This is what I have so far as part of my `~/.emacs/init.el` file, but it still doesn't work as expected.

```
;;Tab and spaces
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq default-tab-width 4)
```

Any help to solve this and/or proper links to learn more will be appreciated..

Comment: What language are you using? Can you give an example of code that's being improperly indented?

Comment: I am trying to do with for javascript .. specifically nodejs code..Sorry, can't put up that code as a example here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your conf (maybe paste pb)

```
;;Tab and spaces
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4) ;; not (setq default-tab-width 4)
```

This configuration is good but sometime another configuration (major-mode or minor-mode configuration) could overwrite your defaults.

For example

- python use `python-indent-offset` or `python-indent` (obsolete since 24.3).
- C++ use `c-indent-level`
- nxml use `nxml-child-indent` and `nxml-attribute-indent`.
- ...

So the solution depends on the languages. You need a proper configuration by language.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks @djangoliv .. there was a error in my config. Any links for javascript configuration?

Comment: It depends on the major-mode you use for javascript. You can try with `(setq js-indent-level 4)`

Comment: So if i understand correctly, `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` actually uses spaces instead of tabs correct?

so my config needs to be `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil) (setq js-indent-level 4)`

Comment: that's sound good. Maybe you can try with `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)` instead of `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`.